# Show that this section of the cone is a hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Show that section of a cone, with vertex at origin and base $x=a$ & $y^2+z^2=b^2$, intersected by a plane parallel to $XY$ axes is a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation of the cone:

$$ \dfrac{y^2 + z^2}{b^2} = \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} $$

Equation of the plane:

$$ z= c $$

Substitute $z=c$ in the equation of the cone

$$ \dfrac{y^2 + c^2}{b^2} = \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} $$
or,
$$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2}  = \dfrac{c^2}{b^2}$$

which is nothing but a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

Allow that at any point A along the x axis, the cross-sectional radius is RA=B, where R is constant.

Then for any plane of fixed Z:

y^2 + Z^2 = (RA)^2

y^2 = R^2 x^2 - Z^2

which is the same as y^2 = Cx^2-D, where C=R^2 and D=Z^2 are constants, which is the formula for a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

The equation should be $y^2+z^2=x^2$ instead of what you wrote (otherwise it's not a cone).  If $z=c$ is constant then the equation gives $y^2+c^2=x^2$ or $y^2-x^2=-c^2$, which is an equation of a hyperbola. (Delete the equation $x=a$.)

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The base of the cone is in the plane $x=a$ and it is $y^2 + z^2 = b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a cone through the vertex is homogeneous. You need to derive a homogeneous equation in $x$, $y$ of degree $2$ using the equation of the guiding curve (base). $$\begin{cases}y^2+z^2=b^2\\ x=a\end{cases}$$

Multiplying both sides of the equation of the sphere by $a^2$, we have:

$a^2y^2+a^2z^2=b^2a^2$

Since we are interested in the intersection with the place $x=a$ and we also want to make the equation homogeneous, it is suitable to consider the equation of the cone: $$a^2y^2+a^2z^2=b^2x^2$$

The equation of a plane parallel to the $X-Y$ plane is of the form $z=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$.

Find the cross section by substituting $z=c$: $$a^2y^2+a^4=b^2x^2\\ \implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$

which is indeed a hyperbola. $\blacksquare$